# PHP - Access value from previously-defined key during array initialization

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to see if it's possible to access the value of a key I previously defined within the same array.

Something like:

```
$test = array(
    'foo' => 1,
    'bar' => $test['foo']
);
```

I know I can always do so after initialization, I am just wondering if it's possible during initialization?

Comment: No, at that point in time `$test` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes, a print-r will produce: Array ( [foo] => 1 [bar] => ).  Also tried $$test['foo'] and $test{'foo'} to the same result.  No problem if it can't be done, but was just curious

Comment: I edited your question to clarify what you're asking

Comment: BTW: The reason is because then it would be impossible to for instance have statements like `$test = intval($test);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `$test` doesn't exist until the full constructor is evaluated.

For example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/naUprJ

```
Notice: Undefined variable: test..
array(2) { ["foo"]=> int(1) ["bar"]=> NULL }
```

It's probably for the best. Imagine of this worked:

```
$test = array('foo' => $test['foo']); // mwahaha
```

If you need to do this a lot, you could create a class that takes keys of a particular format that flag to the class constructor that it should be parsed until all relevant keys are evaluated.

Comment: Makes sense when you put it that way ;) ok, thanks for answering

Comment: FYI, these aren't constructors - It all has to deal with array initialization.